# sphinxQl plain index and RT index?

Tags: sphinx

how to get records from more than one index using sphinxQL .
Here i have faced one problem
all the records i am going to retain in plain index except today records. Today records going to maintain in RT index.

while fetching records from that index ,  we need to get records from recently changed index.

using SphinxAPI it has return records from recently changed index [Rt index]. How to proceed the same way in SphinxQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM index1, index2, index3 WHERE ...
```

SphinxQL is not like mysql, where a comma means a join, in sphinx its closer to a union

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to achieve this will be to create distributed index, which consist of the indexes which you want to use. For example:

```
index tehindex
{
    type = distributed
    local = disk_based_index_name_here
    local = rt_index_name_here
}
```

and then query sphinx with SphinxQL like this:

```
select * from tehindex where match('test');
```